# Jetty 9.3 SSL-ALPN-HTTP2 error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE with HTTPS only

Tags: http, ssl, https, jetty, alpn

I have upgraded a Jetty 9.2 HTTP/1.1 + SSL only server (embedded) to Jetty 9.3.0 (v20150612) HTTP/HTTPS 2.0 (SLL(TLS)-ALPN-HTTP/2). I use JRE 8 (Oracle 1.8.0 Build 45 - b15) and Eclipse.

*** PROBLEM SOLVED BY ANSWER OF JOAKIM : see end of post for solution ***

Before the upgrade HTTP and HTTPS worked fine and it still did by simply rebuilding with the Jetty 9.3 Jar files. Then I upgraded the code (learning from the examples that I managed to find) to incorporate SSL(TLS)-ALPN-HTTP/2-HTTP/1.1. The main example I used is
[in this link with code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/bd27e7d2d480949b32ad6abfbda0c24e6042c1e3/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/Http2Server.java)

A Google Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.130 m) Browser works fine with an http request such as http:// 10.32.1.110:8080/ and the web page displays. But if I open a second tab and try https:// 10.32.1.110:8443/ I receive an error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. I can however connect to webtide.com and get an https session. The interference of a firewall on my system has been excluded. 10.32.??? connections are not passing it as well for the working HTTP as for the failing HTTPS.

This error does NOT block the Jetty server (the server doesn't throw or log an error) and I can go back to the first browser tab and continue to request the web page and I see it updated (I have a time-stamp and counter in it) each time.

In the HTTPS case my handle() method isn't called by Jetty (I have a log line to monitoring that) and I see only the HTTP requests come in the handle() method. The http requests that do arrive in my handle() are of type HTTP/1.1 according to the Jetty request object. According my research that is normal because Google Chrome will NOT do HTTP/2 without SSL/ALPN.

I have been thinking in the direction of SSL and ALPN problems as the reason that HTTPS requests result in the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. The alpn-api-1.1.2.v20150522.jar is added to my Eclipse VM Arguments (JVM Boot classpath equivalent) as "-Xbootclasspath/p:D:\Users\TWO\DATA\Eclipse\alpn-api-1.1.2.v20150522\alpn-api-1.1.2.v20150522.jar" Since then Jetty doesn't complain about ALPN not being on the JVM boot classpath (by throwing an error as it did before). From the Jetty log below the SLL and HTTP/2 are started correctly too.

The Jetty Server starts normally with these logs:

```
2015-06-24 15:53:29.292:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.0.v20150612
2015-06-24 15:53:29.323:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@123772c4{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1, h2c, h2c-17, h2c-16, h2c-15, h2c-14]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2015-06-24 15:53:29.338:INFO:oejus.SslContextFactory:main: x509={jetty.eclipse.org=jetty} wild={} alias=null for SslContextFactory@6f75e721(file:///D:/Users/[removed]/keystores/keystore,file:///D:/Users/[removed]/keystores/keystore)
2015-06-24 15:53:29.495:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@13deb50e{SSL,[ssl, alpn, h2, h2-17, h2-16, h2-15, h2-14, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8443}
2015-06-24 15:53:29.495:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @321ms
```

Here is the relevant Java server code:

```
... standard Jetty imports plus
import org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN;
import org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.server.ALPNServerConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Cipher;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http2.server.HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http2.server.HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory;


QueuedThreadPool oTP = new QueuedThreadPool(20);
this.oServer = new Server(oTP);
this.oServer.setHandler((Handler) this);

HttpConfiguration httpcfg = new HttpConfiguration();
httpcfg.setSecureScheme("https");
httpcfg.setSecurePort(8443);

HttpConnectionFactory httpF=new HttpConnectionFactory(httpcfg);
HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory http2F=new HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory(httpcfg);

ServerConnector http=new ServerConnector(this.oServer,httpF,http2F);
http.setPort(8080);
this.oServer.addConnector(http);

SslContextFactory sslCF=new SslContextFactory();
sslCF.setKeyStorePath(MetaWebServerConfig.getWebServerKeystore()+"keystore"); 
sslCF.setKeyStorePassword("OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4");
sslCF.setKeyManagerPassword("OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g");
sslCF.setTrustStorePath(MetaWebServerConfig.getWebServerKeystore()+"keystore"); 
sslCF.setTrustStorePassword("OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4");

sslCF.setExcludeCipherSuites(
              "SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
              "SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
              "SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
              "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5",
              "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
              "SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
              "SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA");

sslCF.setCipherComparator(new HTTP2Cipher.CipherComparator());

HttpConfiguration httpscfg = new HttpConfiguration(httpcfg);
httpscfg.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory h2F=new HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory(httpscfg);

NegotiatingServerConnectionFactory.checkProtocolNegotiationAvailable();
ALPNServerConnectionFactory alpnF=new ALPNServerConnectionFactory();
alpnF.setDefaultProtocol(http.getDefaultProtocol());

SslConnectionFactory sslF=new SslConnectionFactory(sslCF,alpnF.getProtocol());
HttpConnectionFactory https2F=new HttpConnectionFactory(httpscfg);

ServerConnector http2=new ServerConnector(this.oServer,sslF,alpnF,h2F,https2F);
http2.setPort(8443);
this.oServer.addConnector(http2);

ALPN.debug=false;
this.oServer.start();
```

On request of gregw I tried the sample code that is in the link on the top. I only modified the path to the keystorefor the SslContextFactory. I always use the same keystore file because I know it is ok (see beginning of post - my old HTTP/1.1+SLL worked and used that same keystore.

```
2015-06-25 14:07:14.972:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.0.v20150612
2015-06-25 14:07:15.019:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6f75e721{/,file:///D:/Users/[path]/docroot,AVAILABLE}
2015-06-25 14:07:15.082:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1888ff2c{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1, h2c, h2c-17, h2c-16, h2c-15, h2c-14]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2015-06-25 14:07:15.097:INFO:oejus.SslContextFactory:main: x509={jetty.eclipse.org=jetty} wild={} alias=null for SslContextFactory@4b952a2d(file:///D:/Users/[path]/keystores/keystore,null)
2015-06-25 14:07:15.269:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5594a1b5{SSL,[ssl, alpn, h2, h2-17, h2-16, h2-15, h2-14, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8443}
2015-06-25 14:07:15.269:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @587ms
```

Accessing with http works but with https not and browser shows ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE again.

Tried using IExplorer 11. Same results. Works for http not for https (msg = This page can’t be displayed) not to confuse with 404 (This page cannot be found). IE, in contrast to Chrome did give the 'Cookie' warning when greg's code was used with http but it did not with https.

Is there someone that may have an idea how to solve the above problem.
TIA

*** SOLUTION ***

As suggested by Joakim I added the alpn-boot-8.1.3.v20150130.jar in stead of the alpn-api-1.1.2.v20150522.jar to the boot classpath. Tests reulted in the following combinations working perfectly:

- HTTP/1.1 (HTTP) - done with Google Chrome
- HTTP/1.1 (HTTP) - second try done with IE
- HTTP/2.0 + SSL (HTTPS) - done with Google Chrome
- HTTP/1_1 + SLL (HTTPS) - done with IE
- HTTP/2_0 (HTTP) - didn't test by lack of quick User Agent doing it.

These are the only future combinations I am interested in although I am sure that HTTP/2_0 with SSL will also work.

This [Jetty Documentation link](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-versions) shows the table between JRE version and ALPN JAR file versions to use in case one has the same problem with another JRE.

Many thanks to all that tried to help solve this.

Comment: The version of your alpn-boot.jar and alpn-api.jar are heavily dependent on the *specific version of java* you are running.  Just saying "JRE8" is insufficient to render an answer.  The details must be known to help.  What vendor? (oracle? openjdk? icedtea? ibm? etc).  What build?  What release/update?  Also include your command line startup, as with ALPN there is a specific -Xbootclasspath requirement.

Comment: Can you point the browser you are using at https://webtide.com and see if that works for you (and check that it is http2).  That website is running the released version of 9.3.1, so it should be pretty much the same code as you have.

Comment: Note also that your code looks pretty much correct.  I can't see anything particularly wrong in it.  However to double check, you could try the similar example from the jetty codebase: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/Http2Server.java  and see if that works for you.

Comment: The JRE8 is Oracle JavaSE 1.8 version 1.8.0_05 (2014)

Comment: joakim, The JRE8 is Oracle JavaSE 1.8 version 1.8.0_05 (2014). The command line via Eclipse VM Arguments is  -Xbootclasspath/p:D:\Users\TWO\DATA\Eclipse\alpn-api-1.1.2.v20150522\alpn-api-1.1.2.v20150522.jar. Since the Java JRE8 version is so important for ALPN (which I didn't know/expect) I will upgrade the JRE to the latest version tomorrow and see if the error persists and report back. Thanks.

Comment: greg, yes when connecting to webtide.com the browser automatically selects https and connects without problems (https should be alpn/http/2). Goolgle chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 m. Except for the MBeans related stuff the code you propose to try is almost identical to the one I have here because that code is part of the examples I used to transform my old code to the new code that I posted. As I posted above I'll start with JRE8 update. Thanks.

Comment: I upgraded the JRE to the 1.8.0_45-b15 by asking an automatic upgrade from the ORACLE site. Eclipse now also shows the same JRE version as the project execution environment. The ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error is still occurring. The handle() method is still not called with https but it is with http. Extra info: when requested the server shuts down gracefully and with the expected log lines for both http and ssl.

Comment: This morning I concentrated to see if the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error could have to do with my firewall. However, the 10.32.0.??? dresses are not going to the network and the firewall logs do not have any traces of them, not the working http, nor the failing HTTPS attempts. I think thta may be excluded as a cause also.

Comment: greg, I tried the code in the example link that you provided. I updated/edited the main post with all useful data  as asked in the comments by joakim and you and added the results (Jetty log) of running your code at the end. The http works, https has the same error. I used the same boot class path -X etc as mentioned in the main message. I know that one should be OK because if I remove it Jetty throws an error saying it is missing.

Comment: Tried using IExplorer 11. Same results. Works for http not for https (msg ="This page can’t be displayed") not to confuse with 404 (cannot be found). IE, in contrast to Chrome did give the 'Cookie' warning when greg's code was used with http but not with https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle/OpenJDK Java JRE/JDK you use alpn-boot.jar, not alpn-api.jar ...

- For Java 1.8.0_25, you use alpn-boot-8.1.2.v20141202.jar
- For Java 1.8.0_45, you use alpn-boot-8.1.3.v20150130.jar

See [ALPN / Versions](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-versions) documentation for table of Java to alpn-boot versions.

This is vitally important, as this modifies the SSL/TLS layer of Java itself to add support for the ALPN protocol, required by HTTP/2 to function.

This -Xbootclasspath requirement is mandatory until such time in the future when Java ships with ALPN built-in (which is scheduled for Java 9)

Comment: joakim, thanks. I start looking in it right away and will report back.

Comment: joakim, problem solved with your solution. I have updated the main message with results for all combination tests for which it now works PERFECTLY. I'll keep your comments about JRE8 build version vs ALPN file version in mind for the future.

Comment: Accept the answer, use stackoverflow the way it was intended.  (updating/editing the question saying the answer is correct is not how its done)

Comment: joakim, I am not a frequent stackoverflow user. I'll adapt as I go. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and for offering a solution that worked.

Comment: We all have to start somewhere, welcome to the site.  Careful it can be addicting. :-)